# how to prevent img from stretching its parent

Tags: php, html, css, image, markdown

I'm using markdown language to add posts to the site. So, in order to add image to my post I write

```
![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg)
```

and img appears on the page. There's one problem though - images stretch its parent div if original width of the image exceeds container's width. I use fixed layout so width of container element is hardcoded in css. The Question is: is it even possible to prevent images from stretch my div but instead resize automatically to fit nicely into it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it even possible to prevent images from stretch my div but instead resize automatically to fit nicely into it?

Yes! Try setting:

```
img { max-width: 100%; }
```

As long as the `<img>`'s container has an explicit width, the image shouldn't exceed that width.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot, man! How haven't I figured it out myself?

Comment: what if the container doesn't have an explicit width/height ?